# How can I change 2 textboxes when I select an option from dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4pFf.png]

I would like to change two textboxes when I select option from dropdown but I don't know how can I do it.

I'm using dbml file for connecting to other database. I would like to use 2 properties for 2 textboxes = STOK_FIYAT and STOK_KODU.

```
    private BETASYSEntities db = new BETASYSEntities();
    private NETSISDataContext netsisdb = new NETSISDataContext();     

    public ActionResult Olustur(int FormulID)
    {
        FormulasyonAyrintilari formulasyonayrintilari = new FormulasyonAyrintilari();
        formulasyonayrintilari.FormulID = FormulID;

        ViewBag.StokAdi = new SelectList(netsisdb.TBLSTSABIT, "STOK_ADI", "STOK_ADI");

        return PartialView("_Olustur", formulasyonayrintilari);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Olustur([Bind(Include = "FormulAyrintilariID,FormulID,StokAdi,StokKodu,StokBirim,StokMiktar,StokFiyat")] FormulasyonAyrintilari formulasyonayrintilari)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.FormulasyonAyrintilari.Add(formulasyonayrintilari);
            db.SaveChanges();

            string url = Url.Action("Index", "FormulasyonAyrintilari", new { id = formulasyonayrintilari.FormulID });
            return Json(new { success = true, url = url });

        }

        ViewBag.StokAdi = new SelectList(netsisdb.TBLSTSABIT, "STOK_ADI", "STOK_KODU", formulasyonayrintilari.StokAdi);

        return PartialView("_Olustur", formulasyonayrintilari);
    }

@Html.DropDownList("StokAdi", null, "Lütfen Seçin", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-3 select2", autocomplete = "off" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StokKodu, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StokFiyat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
```

Comment: How do you want to change the 2 textboxes? do you want to change the text or its display or what?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Haitham. im using  netsisdb.TBLSTSABIT table. i can recieved STOK_ADI to my dropdown. i would like to change 2 textboxes value with STOK_KODU and STOK_FIYAT in TBLSTSABIT table when i select dropdown item.

Comment: I have posted my answer, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an action that returns JsonResult which will receive the value STOK_ADI  and returns a JSON Object that has STOK_KODU and STOK_FIYAT

```
public JsonResult GetValuesForSTOK_ADI(string STOK_ADI)
{
 //get the values from the DB for the provided STOK_ADI  
return Json(new {STOK_KODU ="value from db",STOK_FIYAT="value from db"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}
```

In your view, change the declaration for the drop down to add an onchange event that will call the action

```
@Html.DropDownList("StokAdi", null, "Lütfen Seçin", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-3 select2", autocomplete = "off",onchange="updateTextBoxes()"})
```

at the end of the file, create the below javascript function

```
<script>
function updateTextBoxes()
{
  var selectedSTOK_ADI = $("#StokAdi").val();
  $.ajax('@Url.Action("GetValuesForSTOK_ADI","ControllerName")').then(function(data){
$("#StokKodu").val(data.STOK_KODU);
$("#StokFiyat").val(data.STOK_FIYAT);
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its ok :)